# How to setup debug environment for extjs

Tags: extjs

I am using Eclipse EE, and tomcat for a webwork, extjs, hibernate spring application. For spring and hibernate staff, I have remote application debugging settings configured. So I make debug. But for extjs, I have installed firebugs in firefox browser in my ubuntu machine, but I still do not know how to catch break point to see how to trace javascript code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Firebug, go to the script tab. On the top, you can see:

```
Inspect | all | <filename>
```

Click on  to choose the file that contain the javascript you want to track. Once you have selected your file, click on a line number to put a brea kpoint (a big red dot will appear).

You can put several break points in different files. The break point will not disappear if you refresh the page (F5).

This [tutorial](http://michaelsync.net/2007/09/30/firebug-tutorial-script-tab-javascript-debugging) should help you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Actually for Sencha EXT JS I would recommend the excellent App Inspector for Sencha as well. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/app-inspector-for-sencha/pbeapidedgdpniokbedbfbaacglkceae

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Else do provide the link as a comment instead.